# How to extract learned ML model for distinct implementation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm an electronics hobbist, who trying to use ML for modelling errors in sensors, I've trained the model on sensor data in my PC using SVM in scikit-learn in python.

But the use-case for the filtered data is very instantaneous, i.e the sensor data is used to maintain flight of a quadcopter and the raw sensor data should filter through learned model at-least at the rate of 200 Hz, sure my PC can do it, but I cant put my PC on quadcopter, hence I need that model running on a tiny CPU/microcontroller but, no suitable microcontroller of my choice supports python.

So how can I get/extract the mathematical essence of the learned  model, in other words, how can I get that function which was approximated by training so that I can implement it in any microcontroller of my choice.

Just a beginner trying to learn, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which machine learning algorithm(s) are you using?

Comment: C-Support Vector Classification. with RBF kernel

Comment: I'm not an electroinc hobbit, tought arduino can run pyhton

Comment: Support(for python) and MIPS on Arduino are so limited that renders it useless for this application.

Comment: We need to implement the decision function of SVC. Are you solving a classification problem? If yes try logistic regression it very easy to export the model then. It's just a dot product into a sigmoid function

Comment: problem is, data is not linearly separable so non-linear kernels with SVM is a better choice I think.

Comment: This is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360253/how-to-extract-info-from-scikits-learn-classifier-to-then-use-in-c-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to limited computation power, maybe a good option is to use Logistic Regression, it's simple, with low computation cost and it is easily reproducible, it is a simple function like y = w0 + w1.x1 + w2.x2 + ... + wn.xn.

To extract the function you can use the following attributes from scikit-learn LogisticRegresion model (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

> **Attributes**:    **coef_** : array, shape (1, n_features) or (n_classes,
>   n_features)
>
> Coefficient of the features in the decision function.
>
> coef_ is of shape (1, n_features) when the given problem is binary.
>
> **intercept_** : array, shape (1,) or (n_classes,)
>
> Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to the decision function.
>
> If fit_intercept is set to False, the intercept is set to zero.
>   intercept_ is of shape(1,) when the problem is binary.

If you still want to use SVM, I think this similar question could be useful to you: [How to extract info from scikits.learn classifier to then use in C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360253/how-to-extract-info-from-scikits-learn-classifier-to-then-use-in-c-code)